# How do I install / use Devise in Rails 2.3.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have tried to install from the v.1.2.oauth branch of Devise on Github, but I still get an error.

How do I install the devise gem on a rails 2.3.5 application?  In particular, I want the one that works with omniauth

```
gem install devise -v "1.2" 
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'devise' (= 1.2) in any repository

 config.gem 'devise', :git => 'http://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git',
                   :branch => 'omniauth'

ERROR:  Error installing devise:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

c:/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for Rails 2.3.x can be found by installing Devise 1.0.x from the v1.0 branch.

Comment: Hi I saw the docs for that, but wasn't clear how to do that, I used :branch => '1.0" and didn't work -- I'd rather install from command than in the config file, though...is there a way?

Comment: No, I wasn't sure which v to work -- will that still support oauth?

Answer (score 2):

gem install devise -v=1.0.7 worked for me.